How to change DataGrid Cell background color in WinUi 3
How to change DataGrid cell background color in WinUi 3 based on binding value?

DataGridCell background color change example based on binding value & using converter from int to SolidColorBrush. Works for WinUi 3 that uses StudioTemplate project (example: Helpers path) based on MVVM.
IntToSolidColorBrushConverter
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;

namespace YOUR_APP.Helpers;

public class IntToSolidColorBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is int)
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case (byte)1: return (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["SystemFillColorCautionBackgroundBrush"]; // skip
                case (byte)2: return (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["SystemFillColorCautionBackgroundBrush"]; // toUpload
                case (byte)3: return (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["SystemFillColorCriticalBrush"]; // uploading
                case (byte)4: return (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["SystemFillColorSuccessBrush"]; // uploaded
                case (byte)5: return (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["SystemFillColorSolidNeutralBrush"]; // canceled
                default: return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Pink);
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("ExceptionIntToSolidColorConverterValueMustBeAnInt");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

The XAML page resources
<Page
    ...
    xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:helpers="using:YOUR_APP.Helpers">
    <Page.Resources>
        <helpers:IntToSolidColorBrushConverter x:Key="IntToSolidColorBrushConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>
    ...

The XAML DataGrid
<controls:DataGrid 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CanUserReorderColumns="False"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.UploadsList, Mode=OneWay}"
>
<controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn
        Width="auto"
        Binding="{Binding StartDate, Mode=OneWay}"
        Header="StartDate" />

    // The example of custom column that sets it's background color
    // based on binding value and using converter from int to color value
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="auto" Header="State">
        <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="{Binding UploadStateId, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource IntToSolidColorBrushConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UploadState.State, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>

</controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>

Simplified YourPageViewModel
public partial class YourPageViewModel : ObservableRecipient, 
{
    ...
    private ObservableCollection<Upload> _uploadsList = new();
    public ObservableCollection<Upload> UploadsList
    {
        get => _uploadsList;
        set => SetProperty(ref _uploadsList, value);
    }
    ...
}

Simplified Update class
public partial class Upload
{
    public int UploadId { get; set; }
    public byte UploadStateId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
}

I have found an example that overrides GenerateElement but it does not work correctly for large list. It works when you put datagrid in ScroolView, but then you render all the data that is slow.

You are expected to edit your question itself.
